# Print list of lists using *(expansion operator) in single line of code

Tags: python, list, positional-operator

I am trying to print list *lst* using a single line of code

```
lst = [("A",23),("B",45),("C",88)]

print(*lst, sep="\n")
```

Output comes like this:

```
('A', 23)
('B', 45)
('C', 88)
```

What I am expecting is

```
A 23
B 45
C 88
```

However, this can be achieved by the following code

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    print(*lst[i], sep=" ")
```

But I **dont** want to use a "for loop", rather to use * operator or any other technique to accomplish that in a single line of code

Comment: As you have nested `list` I think `for loop` is inevitable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in one line like this:

```
print('\n'.join('{} {}'.format(*tup) for tup in lst))
```

Comment: Was just about to post something like this as an update to my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in one line of code but it does involve a list comprehension (which you may consider a `for` loop):

```
print(*[' '.join([l[0], str(l[1])]) for l in lst], sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
A 23
B 45
C 88
```

Note we need to use `str` to convert the second value in the tuples in `l` into a string for `join`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
print(*map(lambda x: " ".join(x), lst), sep='\n', flush=True)
```